# Python code execution through .net web application : getting error "No module named pyodbc"

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to Execute python script from my *.Net Web Application*. For this I have installed Python from nuget package manager. But I am getting following errors during execution:

I have attempted following code chunks for getting resolution but I am not able to execute it successfully.

Below is the `Python` Scrip to Insert a record in SQL Server database:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 
11.0};SERVER=*****\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=TestDB;UID=sa;PWD=****')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("Insert into Results([EmailID],[Journey]) VALUES (?,?)", 55, 
"JourneyName") 
conn.commit()
Print("Success")
```

Below is the `C#` Code to execute above python file.

```
public string run_cmd(string strPath) //this must not be async
{
    try
    {
       ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
       start.FileName = @"C:\Anaconda\python.exe";
       start.Arguments = string.Format("C:\\Users\\261866\\TestPYCode.py");
       start.UseShellExecute = false;
       start.CreateNoWindow = true; 
       start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
       start.RedirectStandardError = true;
       using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
       {
           using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
           {
               string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
               string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
               return result;
           }
        }
     }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
            return "run till end";
    }
```

As I have executed above c# code I am getting below *Error*:

> Traceback (most recent call last):"C:\Users\261866\TestPYCode.py"
>   import pyodbc Module Not Found Error: No module named 'pyodbc'

Error: No module named 'pyodbc'

Comment: The error speaks for itself.

Comment: Hi @user5173426, Thanks for advise. I have edited my post for more clarity.

Comment: you have to install pyodbc package. How did you installed it? Try to exec command: "npm i pyodbc@latest" from cmd. Remember that you have to be on your application folder.

Comment: **I am getting errors there also** is not helping. You need to specify the errors you are getting. Also, with that edit (errors while installing), the remainder of the question is kind of irrelevant now. So, either delete the question and ask a new one for the `pyodbc` install errors, or edit this and make the installation errors as the primary ask.

Comment: @Presto I have installed pyodbc packages, its saying, 'Requirement already satisfied'.
and installing "npm i pyodbc@latest"  in cmd, giving eror npm is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Presto your view on the error

Comment: any answers guys @Presto

Comment: @ParagS upvote my answer and mark as correct it if helped you

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be the source from where comes pyodbc. If your pyodbc comes from a .whl file then probably you have to install it using pip.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pyodbc-python-development?view=sql-server-2017) is the Microsoft's documentation says how to configure development environment for pyodbc.

Did you try it?

And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files?view=sql-server-2017#installing-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) you've got ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Windows where you can download it and install.

Comment: Thank you @Presto for your suggestions. My colleagues have found a solution to it.

Comment: good for you @ParagS! Would you present solution of this problem? Might be a worth to know it or you could do it for other users with this same problem.